# Spring RESTful Webservice client getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: spring, web-services, rest

Here is my service call:

```
List<ExchangeRateType> eRates = revenueWsClientService.getExchangeRates(e2kId, ControllerConstants.DEFAULT_APPLICATION_ID, 
                    poUiCacheCategorySm.getSailingBasePriceIdS(), poUiCacheCategorySm.getPriceDefinitionIdS().longValue(), selectedSailing.getCurrency(),cSessionId);
```

It is working without any issue at my local Websphere liberty profile server, But if I moved this code into other environment(same WAS server, but its running on AIX OS), I am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Not sure why I am getting this issue, Any thought?

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -14
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1221)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:757)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:440)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:92)
        at com.rccl.pop.web.filters.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:65)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:939)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1036)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:930)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$1.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:253)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:457)
        at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:398)
        at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:380)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:777)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -14
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.util.CollisionCheckStack.findDuplicate(CollisionCheckStack.java:112)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.util.CollisionCheckStack.push(CollisionCheckStack.java:53)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.pushObject(XMLSerializer.java:471)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:574)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:114)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:286)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:532)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:276)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:461)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:292)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:221)
        at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:496)
        at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:483)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter.writeToResult(MarshallingHttpMessageConverter.java:131)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.java:66)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:179)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:596)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:444)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:409)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:287)
        at com.rccl.pop.domain.service.webservices.RevenueRestfulWsClientServiceImpl.getExchangeRates(RevenueRestfulWsClientServiceImpl.java:273)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy114.getExchangeRates(Unknown Source)
        at com.rccl.pop.web.controllers.CategoryDetailsController.getPricingOverrideDiage(CategoryDetailsController.java:731)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        ... 20 more
```

Comment: Might be a JDK version conflict. Try to match the JDK version.

Comment: I use exactly same version of server and JDK.

Comment: Issue is resolved by upgrading JAXB version from 2.0 into 2.2.3

Comment: You might consider adding an answer to your own question, so others will know what fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by changing JAXB version 2.0 to 2.3